# Find Char in Array and if it does not exist then add to new String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am making a small project and I am stuck at the phase:

1. User inserts some chars (x,y,z,k)
2. System tries to search in the existing char array if these exist. If it does not find the chars, the system adds them in a new char Array then it prints (for checking purpose only).

I have tried if ( char[] != charInput) and Arrays.asList(char[].contains(charInput) code but both of them do not work. And ultimately every char gets added or not to the array. What am I doing wrong?

code underneath:

```
package O01_Arrays;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array_16_play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int go = 0;
        int repeat = 0;
        char[] arr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }; // Insert chars
        String[] arr2 = { ".", ".", ".", "." }; // Here the chars that are not
                                                // in the above char will be
                                                // included
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (repeat < 4) // Repeat thread 4 times
        {
            System.out.print("enter character: ");
            String enterValue = in.nextLine();
            char charVal = enterValue.charAt(0); // Transform String to Char
            boolean answer = false; // Boolean to check if it finds new chars or
                                    // not    
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (Arrays.asList(arr[i]).contains(charVal)) {
                    answer = true;
                }
                else if (answer = false) {
                    arr2[go] = enterValue; // Fills with new chars !! DOES NOT
                                            // WORK :( !!!
                }
                System.out.print(arr2[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            go++;
            repeat++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (answer = false)` is probably the issue here - you need to use `==` instead of `=`.

By doing `if (answer = false)`, you're actually setting answer to false.

```
 if (Arrays.asList(arr[i]).contains(charVal)) { //<-- this line evaluates 
                                                // to false, so you go 
                                                // into the else if check
     answer = true;
 } else if (answer = false) { // <-- this line sets "answer" to false and returns true
                              // use if (answer == false) instead
     arr2[go] = enterValue; 
 }
```

Second issue: Your for loop logic is wrong

1) I don't know why you were using the convoluted way of checking if 2 chars are the same, but `arr[i] == charVal` is much easier to read and will work

2) You put the addition code inside the same for loop as the checking code

This is how it should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // check the array arr to                
    if (arr[i] == charVal) { // if it exists, set answer to true
        answer = true;
    }
}

// if answer is false then we didn't find it and we can add it.
if (answer == false) {
    arr2[go] = enterValue; 
}

// check the arr2
for (String c : arr2) {
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: Ok modified. But still does not work. If I insert: x,a,b,c then it adds also a,b,c.

Comment: That makes sense @zypa, your original array is all ".", so of course it adds X A B and C

Comment: Ok. Clear, but the job of the program is to : Check the user's input. If he says a,b,c, then it does nothing. But if user puts something else: x,z, whatever, it should copy these values in the String array. The problem is that it copies altogether a,b,x,y.

Comment: @zypa give me like 3 minutes to type up answer + code

Comment: Ok that solved it! Thanks. (and in less than 15 minutes!)

Comment: @zypa you should use meaningful variable names. Here, 'answer' is not very meaningful. A better name would be 'found' - its name suggests it is a Boolean type, which it is. Then instead of `if (found == false)`, it is clearer and less error-prone to say `if (!found)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow on from Aify's correct answer above, assuming you are just checking on that small array of characters and that the array is already sorted (which it is), then you can use Arrays.binarySearch and remove the for loop altogether.
Below is an updated version of the while section of your code. Hope that is of use even if just as some new code :)

```
while (repeat < 4) // Repeat thread 4 times
{
  System.out.print("enter character: ");
  String enterValue = in.nextLine();
  char charVal = enterValue.charAt(0);
  boolean answer = false;

  // Using binary search method instead of the for loop here
  answer = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,charVal) >= 0 ? true : false;     
  if (answer == false) {
    arr2[go] = enterValue;
  }

  // Print out the stored values
  for ( String str : arr2 ) {
    System.out.println( str );
  }
  System.out.println();
  go++;
  repeat++;
}
```